# Bizarre SignalR error in Firefox even though I'm not using SignalR

Tags: asp.net, firefox, signalr

I get the following error in my FireFox console every time I browse a page. We're not using SignalR. I'm running on IIS using a normal URL and not running against localhost. I've search the whole solution for references to SignalR. I've looked at my Nuget packages.

The other developers that are using the same source code don't get this.

Any idea what would be causing this?

17:26:49.540 The connection to ws://localhost:53574/eb71a6cc096b47a2a20e69ab634ce654/browserLinkSignalR/connect?transport=webSockets&connectionToken=AQAAANCMnd8BFdERjHoAwE%2FCl%2BsBAAAAFfW9yGKzQkKNYfatbm26IQAAAAACAAAAAAAQZgAAAAEAACAAAABT%2FFk32f%2BlQdj987Rt4ENyD7aUhFKuj0mR4yxw67c8qwAAAAAOgAAAAAIAACAAAAAoDTbk3P3hlX8wJTEYpGpCfdtdSnBkhmqMHPf8LxwiUzAAAAAY%2BY46DRpdiNzTKVvpIk2pMJOxPKh4oRxkU1%2BTSciyfWg9eRhXrgafCnv0JiJwfZ9AAAAA2lpt%2BwSVWqTnCJdWjq7o4G1gCxj5AfowzxX9kyeoFvfXbLHkMVPHggC8JysmAtR%2BG6juf616r4T28BEpjLQKDQ%3D%3D&requestUrl=http%3A%2F%mysite.com%2Fadmin%2Fproduct-management%3Fdisplay%3DProduct%2520Model%2520Editor%26id%3D89&browserName=Firefox&userAgent=Mozilla%2F5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0%3B+WOW64%3B+rv%3A44.0)+Gecko%2F20100101+Firefox%2F44.0&tid=9 was interrupted while the page was loading.1 browserLink:62:20265

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the problem comes from Browser Link feature

[image]

Try to disable it by unchecking this option in visual studio.

More info about browser link : http://www.asp.net/visual-studio/overview/2013/using-browser-link